# go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdal

Tags: go, linker, cgo, pkg-config

I am trying to run `go build` on my sources.

```
go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdal
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable contains `/home/fzd/project/lib64`, the path to the dir of the `libgdal.so` file. My `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` contains the path to the dir of a `.pc` file with the following contents :

```
prefix=/home/fzd/project
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib64
deplibdir=${prefix}/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: myLibs
Description: Libs
Requires:
Version: v1.0
Libs: -L${deplibdir} -lgdal
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

I don't know which variable to check. Everything seems fine, and the fun part is that, when I clone my repo elsewhere, I don't have the issue (same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc.)

Does anyone have a clue about what I could check?

I am using go1.11.1, on CentOS7.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few things I did to solve this issue:

- `rm -rf ~/.cache/go-build` : this contained a few build artifacts
- `rm -rf ${MyProject}/{bin,pkg}` : for the same reason

Answer (score 1):

try `yum install glibc-static.x86_64 -y`

I've came across the error like

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
```

and the glibc-static lib fix it.

Comment: There is also a `libstdc++-static`

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me:

```
yum install glibc-static.x86_64 libstdc++-static -y
```

And then removing last build cache

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/go-build
```

And then exporting CXXFLAGS

```
export CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++" CC=/usr/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/bin/g++
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
yum install binutils
```